# NoMethodError rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a module in lib directory with the name "Transpo.rb":

```
module Transpo
  class FT

    def getCities

      ...

    end

  end
end
```

And in the controller I have

```
require 'Transpo.rb'

class TranspoController < ApplicationController

 def index
    @transpo = Transpo::FT.getCities()
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @transpo }
    end
  end
```

But when I run "http://localhost:3000/transpor" always gives the error:

```
NoMethodError in TranspoController#index

undefined method `getCities' for Transpo::FT:Class
```

Why? I've already set the auto_load lib in application.rb but continue with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getCities` is defined as an instance method, but you are calling it as a class method.

Either create an instance with something like `instance = Transpo::FT.new`, or change the definition of `getCities` to be `def self.getCities` to make it into a class method.